# Symfony2 SetSharedMaxAge HTTP caching

Tags: symfony, http-caching

This is what i have:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $response=new Response();
    $response= $this->render('RatingBundle:Default:index.html.twig');

    $response->setPublic(true);
    $response->setSharedMaxAge(15000);

    return $response;
}
```

What's wrong with it?

When i check app env the response header i see

```
age:247
cache-control:max-age=0, must-revalidate=0, public, s-maxage=15000
```

But when i check it in another browser.. i see again age 0 so its loaded again right?

How can i set it public for all?